# How can I use a Wordpress Widget to fill in blanks in HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, widget

Building my first WP widget. (below) Need to provide the client access to input Thumbnail Link, Youtube Link, Project Title and Description. The Widget is storing and retrieving data but I'm stumped on how to send that data to the HTML fields.

```
<?php  
/*
Plugin Name: Red Viking Video
Plugin URI: http://digital-persona.com
Description: Bla Bla Bla
Version: 1.0
Author: Dan
Author URI: Bio Page
Licence: none
*/


class WP_red_viking_video extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(false, $name = __('Red Viking Video'));
        }
    function form($instance) {
        $thumbnail = esc_textarea( $instance['thumbnail'] );
        $you_tube_link = esc_textarea( $instance['you_tube_link'] );
        $project_title = esc_textarea( $instance['project_title'] );
        $project_details = esc_textarea( $instance['project_details'] );
?>

<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thumbnail'); ?>"><?php _e('Thumbnail' ); ?></label>
  <textarea class="widefat" rows="3" cols="30" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thumbnail'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('thumbnail'); ?>"><?php if (!empty($thumbnail)) echo $thumbnail; ?></textarea>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('you_tube_link'); ?>">
    <?php _e('You Tube Link', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?>
  </label>
  <textarea class="widefat" rows="3" cols="30" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('you_tube_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('you_tube_link'); ?>"><?php if (!empty($you_tube_link)) echo $you_tube_link; ?></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('project_title'); ?>">
    <?php _e('Project Title', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?>
  </label>
  <textarea class="widefat" rows="3" cols="30" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('project_title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('project_title'); ?>"><?php if (!empty($project_title)) echo $project_title; ?></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('project_details'); ?>">
    <?php _e('Project Details', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?>
  </label>
  <textarea class="widefat" rows="10" cols="30" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('project_details'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('project_details'); ?>"><?php if (!empty($project_details)) echo $project_details; ?></textarea>
</p>
<?php
        }
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    // Fields
    $instance['thumbnail'] = esc_textarea($new_instance['thumbnail']);
    $instance['you_tube_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['you_tube_link']);
    $instance['project_title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['project_title']);
    $instance['project_details'] = strip_tags($new_instance['project_details']);
    return $instance;
}
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        ?>
<div class="widget featured-video one-third column project"> 

  <!-- ====================== YOU TUBE LINK ======================= --> 
  <a class="youtube" href="<?php echo $you_tube_link; ?>" title="Orchestra London Promo"> 
  <!-- ==================== END YOU TUBE LINK ===================== -->
  <div class="thumbnail slide"> 
    <!-- ===================== THUMBNAIL LINK ======================= --> 
    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /> 
    <!-- =================== END THUMBNAIL LINK ===================== -->

    <div class="project snipit"> 
      <!-- ==================== OVERLAY CONTENT ======================= -->
      <h4><?php echo $project_title; ?></h4>
      <!-- PROJECT TITLE -->
      <p><?php echo $project_details; ?></p>
      <!-- PROJECT DESCRIPTION --> 
      <!-- ================= END OVERLAY CONTENT ===================== --> 
    </div>
  </div>
  </a> </div>
<?php 
    }
}






add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget('WP_red_viking_video');
    })
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored in the `$instance` variable, similarly to what you have in your `update()` function. Just add the following on top of your `widget()` function:

```
$thumbnail       = $instance['thumbnail'];
$you_tube_link   = $instance['you_tube_link'];
$project_title   = $instance['project_title'];
$project_details = $instance['project_details'];
```

Comment: Still missing something, not outputting to the echo tags in the HTML

Comment: My bad. I've updated my answer, please use the updated code instead.

Comment: Thankyou, you are a lifesaver. Knew I was close but couldn't get it.